# Spark history log web page gets stuck

Tags: apache-spark

I'm working with spark2.0.2 and I can't see the history log web page:

[image]

The page gets stuck forever

I checked the history server log and there is no error:

```
/usr/local/spark/logs/spark-hadoop-org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-localhost.out
```

My Spark config in `$SPARK_HOME/config/spark-defaults.conf` :

```
spark.master local[10]
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir file:///tmp/spark-events
spark.history.ui.acls.enable true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing "SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY" in your spark-env.sh. Also, check the number of applications for which you have logs in your "spark.eventLog.dir".